# Connecting to Docker Elasticsearch instance through Java/Spring Boot

Tags: java, elasticsearch, docker, spring-boot, docker-compose

I'm running Elasticsearch instance from Docker. The image is from jHipster docker hub repo: [jhipster/jhipster-elasticsearch/](https://hub.docker.com/r/jhipster/jhipster-elasticsearch/) - I'm using image v1.3.2 because I need Elasticsearch 2.4.0 (to be in line with Spring Boot version of the project).

I'm starting ES container along with Logstash and Kibana images, with `docker-compose`. This are the settings for starting ES container:

```
jhipster-elasticsearch:
    image: jhipster/jhipster-elasticsearch:v1.3.2
    ports:
        - 9400:9200
        - 9500:9300
    volumes:
       - ./log-es-config/elasticsearch_custom.yml:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
```

So I'm using 9400 for REST and 9500 for transport communication.

This is configuration inside `elasticsearch_custom.yml` that is mounted to ES config:

```
cluster.name: "log-cluster"
node.name: "log-node"
http.host: 0.0.0.0
transport.host: 127.0.0.1
transport.tcp.port: 9500
transport.publish_port: 9500
```

When I start container, this is what I get from `http://localhost:9400/_nodes`:

```
"cluster_name": "log-cluster",
  "nodes": {
    "xLsGj2DyTdCF89I7sAToVw": {
      "name": "log-node",
      "transport_address": "127.0.0.1:9500",
      "host": "127.0.0.1",
      "ip": "127.0.0.1",
      "version": "2.4.0",
      "build": "ce9f0c7",
      "http_address": "172.18.0.5:9200",
      "settings": {
        "cluster": {
          "name": "log-cluster"
        },
        ... (I can put all response if needed)
```

**JAVA API:**

Now I'm trying to connect to this ES node like this:

```
    @Bean
    public ElasticsearchOperations logsElasticsearchOperations() throws UnknownHostException {
        Settings settings = Settings.settingsBuilder()
            .put("cluster.name", "log-cluster")
            .put("node.name", "log-node")
            .build();

        Client client = TransportClient.builder()
            .settings(settings)
            .build()
            .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 9500)));


        ElasticsearchTemplate template = new ElasticsearchTemplate(client);
        template.createIndex(ProcessLog.class);
        log.debug("Elasticsearch for logs configured.");
        return template;
    }
```

The error I'm getting is the most famous one:

**`Caused by: org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9500}]`**

I googled and tried different config approaches, also with `client.transport.sniff` set to `false`, but non of those worked. Now I spent lots of time trying to configure this one and I'm still missing something.

Thanks in advance for help.

**UPDATE:**

There is also embedded ES instance running when I start the app. So host ports config is like this:

- Embedded ES: 9200 (http), 9300 (tcp)
- Docker's ES: 9400 (http), 9500 (tcp)

Here is full `docker-compose.yml`:

```
    version: '2'
    services:
    jhipster-elasticsearch:
        # elasticsearch 2.4.0 - to be in line with spring boot version
        image: jhipster/jhipster-elasticsearch:v1.3.2
        ports:
            - 9400:9200
            - 9500:9300
        volumes:
           - ./log-es-config/elasticsearch_custom.yml:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
    jhipster-logstash:
        image: jhipster/jhipster-logstash:v2.2.1
        command: logstash -f /conf/logstash_custom.conf
        ports:
            - 5000:5000/udp
            - 6000:6000/tcp
        volumes:
            - ./logstash-log-es-conf/:/conf
    jhipster-console:
        image: jhipster/jhipster-console:v2.0.1
        ports:
            - 5601:5601
    jhipster-zipkin:
        image: jhipster/jhipster-zipkin:v2.0.1
        ports:
            - 9411:9411
        environment:
            - ES_HOSTS=http://jhipster-elasticsearch:9400
            - ZIPKIN_UI_LOGS_URL=http://localhost:5601/app/kibana#/dashboard/logs-dashboard?_g=(refreshInterval:(display:Off,pause:!f,value:0),time:(from:now-1h,mode:quick,to:now))&_a=(filters:!(),options:(darkTheme:!f),panels:!((col:1,id:logs-levels,panelIndex:2,row:1,size_x:6,size_y:3,type:visualization),(col:7,columns:!(stack_trace),id:Stacktraces,panelIndex:7,row:1,size_x:4,size_y:3,sort:!('@timestamp',desc),type:search),(col:11,id:Log-forwarding-instructions,panelIndex:8,row:1,size_x:2,size_y:3,type:visualization),(col:1,columns:!(app_name,level,message),id:All-logs,panelIndex:9,row:4,size_x:12,size_y:7,sort:!('@timestamp',asc),type:search)),query:(query_string:(analyze_wildcard:!t,query:'{traceId}')),title:logs-dashboard,uiState:())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to get this working by defining the `transport.host` as `0.0.0.0` inside `elasticsearch_custom.yml`, so the instance binds to the container's ip.

Maybe this should be also default setup for `elasticsearch.yml` on the project's github [repo](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-console/tree/master/jhipster-elasticsearch).

Comment: That was exactly the point that I missed. ```transport.host: 0.0.0.``` did the job

Answer (score 0):

From your docker compose file, port 9500 on the host is mapped to port 9300 inside the container, i.e.:

```
ports:
    - 9500:9300
```

So since port 9500 is the TCP port outside of the Docker container, in your `elasticsearch_custom.yml` config file you should have this instead

```
transport.tcp.port: 9300
transport.publish_port: 9300
```

or simply leave those two lines out since 9300 is the default TCP port.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I just tried that but the same error is still present.

Comment: Do you mind sharing the full `docker-compose.yml` file so we can get a real view of the context?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend taking a step back and installing the Head Plugin(https://github.com/mobz/elasticsearch-head) so you can get a view of your cluster, it will display the detail information of the cluster name.

Also maybe try sending a simple index request from the command line to make sure you can connect to your cluster at all.